# Django/HTML5 audio tag not working for specific files

Tags: python, django, html

I am generating one `mp3` and one `ogg` file from a base64 encoded data in database.

Then using the HTML code in Django template

```
<audio controls="control">
             <source src="{{STATIC_URL}}audio/voice_{{each.id}}_.mp3" type="video/mp3">
             <source src="{{STATIC_URL}}audio/voice_{{each.id}}_.ogg" type='audio/ogg; codecs=vorbis'>
             <p>Your user agent does not support the HTML5 Audio element.</p>
</audio>
```

The path is right. the file also exist, but the audio player appears and then in a second disappears from the browser. 
I had a sample mp3 file so just for testing I gave a static `src` path and it was working fine.

These base64 encoded/Decoded mp3 file do work locally once I save them and play, but not in the browser. 
I think I might be decoding and creating the file wrong so here is the code of that too.

```
encoded_mp3_str = record.callRecord
decoded_mp3_str = base64.b64decode(encoded_mp3_str)
with open(settings.BASE_DIR+'/play/static/audio/voice_'+str(record.id)+'_'+ '.mp3', 'w') as mp3_file:
    mp3_file.write(decoded_mp3_str)
    mp3_file.close()
with open(settings.BASE_DIR+'/play/static/audio/voice_'+str(record.id)+'_'+ '.ogg', 'w') as ogg_file:
    ogg_file.write(decoded_mp3_str)
    ogg_file.close()
```

Where `record` is a Model object and `record.callRecord` is something like this:

```
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
```

What am I missing ?
Thanks

Comment: Are you getting any messages from the browser console? Do you intend to be writing the same data for the `.mp3` and the `.ogg` files?

Comment: @Noelkd No Error in the Console. and yes both the file works.